# VS 2010 remote debugger breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, breakpoints, remote-debugging

1) Make an Windows account on Host Machine. Log In.

2) Make an Windows account, with same user name and password as Host Machine, on the Remote Machine. Log In.

3) Copy all .pdb files to same directory as .exe on the Remote Machine.

4) Run Remote Debugger on the Remote Machine.

5) Tools -> Options

6) Radio Button to "No Authentication (native only)" and Check "Allow any user to debug", OK.

7) Run the .exe (debug build) on the Remote Machine.

8) On the Host Machine, open your solution.

9) Debug -> Attach To Process

10) Transport : Remote ( Native only with no authentication )

11) Qualifier : Server IP

12) Refresh

13) Choose the application to debug.

14) Attach

application seems to be running in the visual studio but all the breakpoints grey out with the following comment :

breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document

I did the folowing I deploy my applicatiob (including the pdb files) in the remote pc under c:\abc
I add the symbols location as you can see in the screenshot and I try to debug from my pc to the remote pc butstill no breackpoint

[image]
Any Idea?

Comment: You might have solved it now. But here is a nice recipe: http://codewut.de/content/visual-studio-and-remote-debugging-easy-way

Comment: You should be completely sure that sources and PDBs are in sync in both ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that if you used native you cannt debug c# .net application

Comment: What should be used?

Answer (score 5):

When remotely debugging native code, your symbols must be on the machine with Visual Studio, not on the remote machine.

To let VS find the symbols, just add a folder containing the symbols to your symbol path. Go Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols, and add the folder to the list.

Comment: I did the folowing I deploy my applicatiob (including the pdb files) in the remote pc under c:\abc
I add the symbols location as you can see in the screenshot and I try to debug from my pc to the remote pc butstill no breackpoint

Comment: Which machine was that screenshot from? The remote machine or your local machine? Did you put the symbols in C:\abc on *both* machines?

Comment: To clarify: the symbols path you're setting is the path to the native symbols on the _local_ machine. It has nothing to do on where you deployed the symbols on your remote machine.

Comment: It seems like you could use a network path to the PDB files on the remote machine.